# Spring Opens new Hikari Pool eventhough old one already exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I use hikaridatasource(3.4.5) and spring boot(2.4) and spring jpa to access database

When I checked my database session I see too much connection on my database.I set my max and min pool size and my expectation is there is no more connection than my maximum pool size

```
maximumPoolSize=5
minimumIde=3
```

When I check my spring logs I see to many Hikari pool,Somehow if exist pool is useless,then why I see connections?
Can spring boot open hikari pool and cant destroy old one?Why  new pool created?

When I check hikari code,As I understand HikariPool-n means n pool name

LOGGER.info("{}-Starting...",configuration.getPoolName());

com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1

com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2

com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3
```

Comment: Check more properly how many your HikariPool created, there should be only one pool alive. Hikari pool created when hibernate want connection and there is no active pool [link to git](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource.java#L112).

Comment: There are more than one hikaripool created but I dont understand it is root cause.If hikari pool is destroyed then why old connections not die?And if hibernate want more connection that time it must hit my maximum pool count am I right.In my case there much more connection my maximum pool limit